# Setting Selection of a UIButton with images iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a number of UIButtons in a vertical Line. All buttons have images `btnImage.png btnImage_selected.png.`

The Actions are set as `UIEventTouchUpInside`. Now i have added selected To `HighLighted` state of teh button.

When I press on button it shows the selected version but when i lift the finger of , it changes back to normal.

How can I make code so when the button is pressed it changes it state and stick to selected image and when another button is pressed it automatically changes back to normal state where as other button normal state is changed to selected one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the image for the `Highlighted` state will only set the image when it's highlighted.  You'll need to set the image for all states, when the button is pressed.

Hook up all IBActions for each button to `buttonPressed`

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *arrayOfButtons;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.arrayOfButtons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, button10, nil];
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    for (UIButton *button in self.arrayOfButtons)
    {
        if (! [button isEqual:sender])
        {
            [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        } else
        {
            [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnImage_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I have 10 buttons :) I don't think this is a good way for me

Comment: Okay, I updated my answer to combine the image setting into a single IBAction

Answer (score 0):

If you make the buttons in a `xib` you can you an `IBOutletCollection` to hold a reference to all the buttons. Or you can add a property that holds all the buttons.

```
- (NSArray *)allButtons
{
  return _allButtons = _allButtons ?: @[
    button01,
    button02,
    button03,
    button04,
    button05,
    button06,
    button07,
    button08,
    button09,
    button10,
  ];
}
```

Now you need an method that will set one button to active

```
- (void)setActiveButton:(UIButton *)activeButton
{
  for (UIButton *button in self.allButtons) {
    button.enabled = button == activeButton;
  }
}
```